# Peach disease identification

Tags: trees, diseases, leaves, fungus, peaches

## Peach Tree is Sick

My peach tree is suffering from curling leaves.
The issue started last year and persists.
This is a young tree and it only produced 3 fruits last season.

I suspected it's a fungal infection of some sort.
So I read a bit of online research and decided to spray it with copper fungicide, which I did twice this Spring.
Around the same time I also pruned the tree.

Within 10 meters (~30 feet) there is a [cherry tree which is sick](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/64425/cherry-tree-is-sick) but seemingly in a different way.
I am only mentioning it for the context.

Does the tree have a chance of survival?
What should I do?

### Overall View of the Tree

[image: overall view of the tree]

### Pictures of the Affected Leaves and Blooms

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Round up the usual suspects. Unusual weather, hot or cold, wet or dry. Any insects? Any fungus? Any whacky chemicals nearby?

Comment: @BobaFit We have not used any Roundup in our yard as far as I am aware. Not seeing insects around. Chemicals-free yard generally speaking. In terms of insects, we have some ants in the area, and (I think) aphids on the other cherry tree. No unusual weather this year besides Spring being a bit late. Fungus is what I suspect and want to get confirmed.