# Cherry disease identification

Tags: diseases, leaves, insects, cherries

## Cherry Tree is Sick

I have a cherry tree that was planted 3 years ago.
It is a hybrid of three different species (one branch is native, the two other are not).
The tree looked healthy and did grow relatively fast for a couple of season.

This spring I noticed that two of it's vertically-pointing branches have the leaves dying off.
I noticed about a couple dozen of leaves on the *healthy* branches infested with insects, accompanied by ants.
There were also a few ladybugs around.

Finally, this year I see active gummosis happening all over the tree.
Did I prune the tree too much and too poorly?

Is it suffering from more than one disease?
How do I help the tree recover?

Within 10 meters (~30 feet) there is a [peach tree which is sick](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/64424/peach-disease-identification) but seemingly in a different way.
I am only mentioning it for the context.

### Overall View of the Tree

[image]

### The Affected Branches

[image]

### Gummosis Examples

[image]
[image]

### Insects Spotted

[image]
[image]

### Fruits

[image]